# Exclude .svn from _bin_deployableAssemblies directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild

In VS 2010 for ASP.NET MVC 3 project there is an option to add a "Deployable Dependencies" folder (_bin_deployableAssemblies) (click right button on web project), files contained in this directory will be copied to the /bin directory.

If you are using Subversion, this task will also try to copy .svn folder and its content, which will result in an error due to a collision with /bin 's own .svn folder.

**Question:** how do you exclude .svn folder from being copied to /bin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following seems to do the trick:

1. backup and open file `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` (on my computer found in `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications`)
2. find target named `_CopyBinDeployableAssemblies`
3. in that task find line:

.

```
<CreateItem 
    Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\*.*"
    Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies')">
```

and add `Exclude` attribute as follows:

```
<CreateItem 
    Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\*.*"
    Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies')"
    Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\.svn\**\*">
```

Comment: Those .svn folders annoyed the heck out of me before we moved over to TFS... now I have a whole new set of things to be annoyed about =P

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for subdirectories of `_bin_deployableAssemblies`, like for `_bin_deployableAssemblies\amd64`

Comment: To include also subdirectories `Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\.svn\**\*.*"` seems to work